# How to make object to accept generate differnt parameters for different types

Tags: c++

The title is perhaps confusing but I really did not knew how to put it in a better way.

I have a class Monsters which inherits the base values from class Creature, but I want to be able to generate different of monsters based on the values that I have in the enum Monsters. The code that I provided does not work, but this is my attempt and I think I am pretty close but cannot finish it.

Suppose that Spider can have energy from 1-3 and Dragon can have energy from 10-20. How can I make so that for differnt type of monster it will generate different amount of energy?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

enum Monsters
{
    Spider,
    Griffon,
    Dragon
};
class Creature
{
public:
    Creature() {}
    Creature(int lifes, int damage)
    {
        this->lifes = lifes;
        this->damage = damage;
    }
    virtual ~Creature() {}
protected:
    int lifes;
    int damage;
};

template <class T>
class Monster() : public Creature()
{
public:
    Monster() : Creature() {} 
    Monster(int lifes, int damage, int energy) : Creature(lifes, damage)
    {
        maxPower = rand() % 10;
        minPower = rand() % maxPower;
        energy = rand() % maxPower + minPower;
    }
    virtual void stats()
    {
        cout << "Lifes left: " << this->lifes << endl;
        cout << "Damage: " << this->damage << endl;
        cout << "Energy: " << this->energy << endl;
    }
protected:
    int energy;
private:
    int minPower;
    int maxPower;
};
int main()
{
    Monster<Dragon> *dragonOne = new Dragon(5, 10, 10);
    dragonOne->stats();
    return 0;
}
```

Pleas ask for more info, or edit this post accordingly if needed.

Comment: Tip: Use [constructor lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor). Also don't use `this->x`, just `x` is fine unless there's a conflicting local variable.

Comment: **WARNING**: Using [`rand()` can be highly problematic](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) and you’re strongly encouraged to use an appropriate [random number generator facility in the Standard Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that produces high-quality random values. Using `time(NULL)` as a random number will produce identical results if run in the same second, and on many platforms `rand()` is *barely* random at all.

Comment: I am new to C++ and just want to make sure that I am pointing to correct variable, but it is valid point. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain "does not work" in more technical terms? What are the *exact* errors you get?

Comment: I think the problem here is you're pinning your template argument to a `class`, which those enum things are not. Just relax it, remove the `class` part. You may not even need a template class at all, just capture that enum as a constructor property. Note the name `Monsters` should probably be `MonsterType` or something so you can do `Monster(const MonsterType type, ...)`

Comment: i am not able to send one of the values from the enum, when creating at main function.

Comment: Instead of mixing both inheritance and templates, you could have classes that derive from Monster.  Example: Spider, Griffon and Dragon would all derive from Monster, who in turn derives from Creature.  Otherwise you need to create a whole new layer of data just to assign different energies to each enum.

Comment: How can i do that in terms of code

Comment: 1. Relax it to `<T>`. 2. Remove the template, use an argument.

Comment: Unless Dragon and Spider are substantially different in terms of code you don't really need a template at all. If they are different you need explicit subclasses, not a template. A template here is just a mistaken excursion. You'll probably want the ability to reflect on what type of monster you're dealing with, which you don't get with a template, but you do if that's a property.

Comment: I thought of doing like you mentioned, but just want to try somethings that i am not comfortable with

Comment: Exploring C++ and trying new things is to be encouraged, but this is isn't an appropriate use of templates. It doesn't add any benefits, it only complicates the code.

Comment: Don't pass in energy to the Monster constructor - pass in maxPower and minPower and use those to caculate energy using random values.

Comment: I'd expect that `enum` to be used to look up defaults or ranges so that when you're generating a random monster of type X it will have some predictable statistics and abilities. If you're looking to create actual subclasses you need a factory method. If you're not, you'll need to capture that as a property so you can reflect on it.

Comment: Thank you for your input, seems like the most reasonable thing to is to split in different classes which inherits from creature, because factory does not ring a bell to me right now.